# How to retrieve more than 30 documents from Sharepoint using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I've been given the job of supporting an old asp.net system, which uses web forms.  This is painful enough, but on top of that, there's a page which retrieves all documents associated with a customer, and lists them on screen.  The documents are saved on SharePoint.  The main problem is that this list is only retrieving a maximum of 30 documents, so any customer that has more than 30 doesn't see all of their letters.  The second problem is that I know next to nothing about SharePoint, and this is someone else's code, so I don't know where to start to even diagnose this problem.  Here is what I think is the code to retrieve the documents:

```
public List<SharepointDocument> ProcessListResults(XmlNode xml, string foldername)
    {
        List<SharepointDocument> docs = new List<SharepointDocument>();
        SharepointDocument newdoc = null;
        string namespaceURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
        string listNamespaceURI = "#RowsetSchema";
        string directoryNamespaceURI = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset";

        // Now associate with the xmlns namespaces (part of all XML nodes returned 
        // from SharePoint) a namespace prefix which we can then use in the queries 
        XmlNamespaceManager namespaceMngr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.OwnerDocument.NameTable);

        namespaceMngr.AddNamespace("sp", namespaceURI);
        namespaceMngr.AddNamespace("z", listNamespaceURI);
        namespaceMngr.AddNamespace("rs", directoryNamespaceURI);

        // Run the XPath query and return the result nodes 
        foreach (XmlNode row in xml.SelectNodes("//z:row[@ows_Title]", namespaceMngr))
        {
            newdoc = new SharepointDocument();
            newdoc.Title = GetAttributeStringValue(row, "ows_Title");
            newdoc.Modified = GetAttributeDateValue(row, "ows_Modified");
            newdoc.Id = GetAttributeStringValue(row, "ows_UniqueId");
            newdoc.Created = GetAttributeDateValue(row, "ows_Created_x0020_Date");
            newdoc.ModifiedBy = GetAttributeStringValue(row, "ows_Editor");
            newdoc.Filename = GetAttributeStringValue(row, "ows_FileLeafRef");
            newdoc.DocumentStatus = (SharepointDocument.SharepointDocumentStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(SharepointDocument.SharepointDocumentStatus), GetAttributeStringValue(row, "ows__ModerationStatus"));
            newdoc.DocumentVersion = GetAttributeStringValue(row, "ows__UIVersionString");

            if (UseRestrictedDownloadUrl)
            {
                string url = string.Format("download.aspx?Folder={0}&Filename={1}",
                    foldername, newdoc.Filename);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Attempting to create URL <" + url + ">");
                newdoc.Url = url; 
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Attempting to create URL <" + SPSiteURL + GetAttributeStringValue(row, "ows_FileRef") + ">");
                newdoc.Url = SPSiteURL + GetAttributeStringValue(row, "ows_FileRef");
            }
            docs.Add(newdoc);
        }

        logger.Debug("SharepointLibrary document count = " + docs.Count);

        return docs;

    }
```

I can't see anything in here that would cause this problem.  I suspect the problem has to be with SharePoint - when I log into SharePoint, and onto a user's letters page (a user that has more than 30 letters), the page has 30 letters per page, and the first page of letters are the same ones being brought back by the web app.  This seems like too much of a coincidence.  So how might I diagnose this problem in SharePoint?  Anybody any idea what could be causing this?  Is there a setting somewhere in SharePoint that I don't know about?

Comment: This is processing an already retrieved XmlNode.  I would look at the code that calls this and passes in that XmlNode first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint list display 30 items with OOB setting, if you want to display more items, you need update your view settings.
[image]

What's more, you could use [CSOM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) to query SharePoint data.

Sample code to get user specific documents.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            string login = "lee@domain.onmicrosoft.com"; //give your username here  
            string password = "pw"; //give your password  
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            string siteUrl = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/tst";
            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
                var user = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(login);
                clientContext.Load(user);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyDoc3");
                CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                //you could add query condition to query based on other conditions
                query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><And><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x0101</Value></BeginsWith><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + user.Id + "</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>";                
                var listItems = list.GetItems(query);
                clientContext.Load(listItems);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (var item in listItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.FieldValues["FileRef"]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("done");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job.